# How do you turn lists with multiple characters into strings?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm quite new to programming and have looked on many answers to similar questions but they don't produce the desired result for me. Is it possible for any of you guys to help me?
example code:

```
shapes = ["tri", "angle"]

groupedShapes = "triangle"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [doc's](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.join):

> **string.join(words[, sep])** 
>   Concatenate a list or tuple of words with intervening occurrences of sep. The default value for sep is a single space character.

```
shapes = ["tri", "angle"]
groupedShapes = "".join(shapes)
# "triangle"
```